# Scrollable Bootstrap Carousel/Slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

good day. I have a Carousel that slides vertically. I want it to be controlled by the mouse wheel. Can anyone help me on its JS?

Here's the mark up

```js
$('#carousel').bind('mousewheel', function(e){$(this).carousel('next');});
```

```css
<style>
       <!-- html, body {
            height: 100%;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }

        body {
            background: #fff;
            min-height: 600px;
        }

            body * {
                font-family: Arial, Geneva, SunSans-Regular, sans-serif;
                font-size: 14px;
                color: #666;
                line-height: 22px;
            }-->

        #wrapper {
            width: 100%;
            min-width: 900px;
            height: 500px;
            position: relative;
            left: 0;
        }

        #carousel div {
            height: 100%;
            float: left;
        }

        #carousel img {
            min-width: 100%;
            min-height: 100%;
        }
    </style>
    <style type="text/css">
        .carousel-inner.vertical {
            height: 100%;
        }

            /*.carousel .item img {*/
            /*margin: 0 auto;*/ /* Align slide image horizontally center */
            /*}*/

            .carousel-inner.vertical > .item {
                -webkit-transition: .6s ease-in-out top;
                -o-transition: .6s ease-in-out top;
                transition: .6s ease-in-out top;
            }

        @media all and (transform-3d), (-webkit-transform-3d) {
            .carousel-inner.vertical > .item {
                -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .6s ease-in-out;
                -o-transition: -o-transform .6s ease-in-out;
                transition: transform .6s ease-in-out;
                -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
                backface-visibility: hidden;
                -webkit-perspective: 1000;
                perspective: 1000;
            }

                .carousel-inner.vertical > .item.next,
                .carousel-inner.vertical > .item.active.right {
                    top: 0;
                    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
                    transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
                }

                .carousel-inner.vertical > .item.prev,
                .carousel-inner.vertical > .item.active.left {
                    top: 0;
                    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
                    transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
                }

                    .carousel-inner.vertical > .item.next.left,
                    .carousel-inner.vertical > .item.prev.right,
                    .carousel-inner.vertical > .item.active {
                        top: 0;
                        -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
                        transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
                    }
        }

        .carousel-inner.vertical > .active {
            top: 0;
        }

        .carousel-inner.vertical > .next,
        .carousel-inner.vertical > .prev {
            top: 0;
            height: 100%;
            width: auto;
        }

        .carousel-inner.vertical > .next {
            left: 0;
            top: 100%;
        }

        .carousel-inner.vertical > .prev {
            left: 0;
            top: -100%;
        }

            .carousel-inner.vertical > .next.left,
            .carousel-inner.vertical > .prev.right {
                top: 0;
            }

        .carousel-inner.vertical > .active.left {
            left: 0;
            top: -100%;
        }

        .carousel-inner.vertical > .active.right {
            left: 0;
            top: 100%;
        }
    </style>
```

```html
 <div id="wrapper">
        <!-- wrap @img width -->
        <div id="carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="3000">
            <!-- Indicators -->
                  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
                <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="4"></li>
            </ol>

            <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
            <div class="carousel-inner vertical" role="listbox">
                <div class="item active">
                    <img src="img/image1.jpg" alt="First Slide" />
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="img/image2.jpg" alt="Second Slide" />
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="img/image3.jpg" alt="Third Slide" />
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="img/image4.jpg" alt="Forth Slide" />
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="img/image5.jpg" alt="Fifth Slide" />
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Controls -->
            <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
            </a>
            <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Please give me any recommendation about my problem. I tried to search both on google and on this site but the JS is not working in my carousel.

Please I need your help. Thank you in advance.

P.S. The size of the image im using is 1920 x 1020

Comment: Please post the javascript you're using, and describe in detail the unexpected behaviour or error.

Comment: `$('#carousel').bind('mousewheel', function(e){$(this).carousel('next');});`
I tried this JS but I dont know why its not working (im new at js)

Comment: You can click "edit" and add the code to your question.

Comment: i already edit it sir

Comment: Looks fine **[here](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/845mkb2o/)**

Comment: its perfectly working for auto transition but manual transition using mouse wheel or scroll it not working

Comment: @kulotskie : Create a fiddle and share with us.

Comment: this is the fiddle of my carousel [Testing](http://jsfiddle.net/dranir45/j7kpLb8s/) its working properly in  fiddle but when im trying to move it to my HTML the script is not working can you help me?

Comment: I think the Framework and Extention (jQuery 2.1.0 and Bootstrap 3.2.0) is my problem but when i try to link it in my HTML it doesnt work also :( 
pls help me

Answer (score 0):

First add an listener for Mousewheel action:

```
var carousel = document.getElementById("carousel");
if (carousel.addEventListener) {
    // IE9, Chrome, Safari, Opera
    carousel.addEventListener("mousewheel", MouseWheelHandler, false);
    // Firefox
    carousel.addEventListener("DOMMouseScroll", MouseWheelHandler, false);
}
// IE 6/7/8
else carousel.attachEvent("onmousewheel", MouseWheelHandler);

function MouseWheelHandler() {
$('#carousel').carousel('next');
}
```